# Prove that AA" ,CC" is perpendicular to bisector of B

Tags: geometry, triangles

**Question -** 
The internal bisector of the $\angle B$ of $\Delta ABC$ meets the sides $B'C'$ and $B'A'$ of the medial triangle in the points $A''$ and $C''$ respectively. Prove that $AA''$ and $CC''$ are perpendicular to the bisector of $\angle B$ and that $B'A''=B'C''$. (*Similar results holds for external bisector*)

**Figure** - [image]

**My attempt -**

First I tried to make $\angle AA''B = \angle AA'B$ so that they will be in same segment $AB$ so they will be concyclic and angle in semi-circle is $90^o$ so I will get result.

But even after spending sufficient amount of time I am not able to show that those angles are equal. I have tried angle bisector theorem, similarity, etc but none of them worked out.

Any hint will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Source: CTPCM (Olympiad book)

Comment: My proof is based on the diagram you have drawn. I think your diagram has not been drawn according to the common naming convention. The proper diagram  will have the positions of B' and C' interchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Draw X on BC such that A''X // AB. Note that the green triangle is congruent to the blue triangle (by AAS).  In addition, each of these triangles are isoscelss because their base angles are equal.

Then, BB' = B'A". Since Ac' = C' B already because of the median trianlge. C' is then the center of of the circle with radius C'A = C'B = C'A". that circle will pass through A, B, A''. This means $\angle AA"B = 90^0$. This further means AA" is perpendicular to the angle bisector of ∠ABC.

---

[image]

In our usual naming convention, A' is a point on the side opposing A. That is, A' is on BC. Similarly B' is on AC;  and C' is on AB.

Comment: Not able to crack your hint..can you further explain..

Comment: @User12002 I have added the second picutre in my answer. If your picture is drawn correctly, the problem is not that difficult to solve. If further assistance is needed, do say so.

Comment: @User12002 Besides, I have added more details to my previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

\begin{align}
\angle BA_2C_1+\angle C_1BA_2
&=
\angle A_1C_2B+\angle C_2BA_1=
\beta
,\\
\angle BA_2C_1&=\angle C_1BA_2
=
\angle A_1C_2B=\angle C_2BA_1=
\tfrac\beta2
.
\end{align}

Hence, triangles $C_1BA_2$ and $A_1C_2B$ are isosceles,

\begin{align}
|C_1A|&=|C_1B|=|C_1A_2|
,\\
|A_1B|&=|A_1C|=|A_1C_2|
,
\end{align}

$A_1$ and $C_1$ are the centers of the circles with 
diameters $|AB|$ and $|BC|$, hence
$\angle BA_2A=\angle CC_2B=90^\circ$.